# Css Show On Hover For My Nav

Tags: css, hover, show-hide

I usually dont have problems with css, and I'm made this nav menu myself but I just can't seem to understand why it will not show my div when I hover over an item ... I create a jsfiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/LuLTM/ with all the code as well ...

```
#beautyworld #beautyhealth {display:none;}
#beautyworld #beautyhealth:hover {color:black;display:block!important}
```

I want when hover over div #beautyworld for the div #beautyhealth to appear ... I just dont understand why my css is not working .... Could someone please advise ? Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are trying to have fire a hover over something that is currently 'display:none'.  Since display none collapses the element, there is nothing to hover.  You heed to have it hover at a relative parent level to cause the display of the child.

For example:

```
#beautyworld > div { display:none; }
#beautyworld:hover > div { color:black; display: block !important; }
```

Comment: I also chose to provide an example using a direct descendant selector as I generally look at rules with multiple IDs in it to be bad practice but its ancillary to your problem.

Comment: Your A God ... TY ... I love overstock lol ... 2 hours of busting my head on this thing and Scott figures it out in under 2m lol :) Thankx again